# Solr exclusion on stats.field?

Tags: lucene, solr, statistics, facet

> One can tag specific filters and exclude those filters when faceting. This is generally needed when doing multi-select faceting.

Is something similar possible for the stats.field?

```
stats.field={!ex=foo}price // does not work
```

I have a price slider and I need the max price as if the price filter is not set.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone concerned with this question/issue is suggested to go [vote up this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3177) posted to the Apache Solr Jira site. (Free Apache account required.) If you are a Solr developer and wish to work on coding this feature enhancement, we salute you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Use stats=true&stats.field=price

Comment: I want a way to make stats.field=price ignore queries like q=price:[1 TO 100]. With q=price:[1 TO X] the maximum price calculated by stats.field=price can only lower or equal to X

Comment: Just found the posting from 2011 with the exact same problem. Hope to find a solution that has already been implemented in 2019.